# How to access to elements of confusion matrix in H2O for python?

Tags: python, h2o

I made a grid search that contains 36 models.

For each model the confusion matrix is available with :

`grid_search.get_grid(sort_by='a_metrics', decreasing=True)[index].confusion_matrix(valid=valid_set)`

My problematic is I only want to access some parts of this confusion matrix in order to make my own ranking, which is not natively available with `h2o`.

Let's say we have the `confusion_matrix` of the first model of the `grid_search` below:

```
+---+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+
|   |   0   |   1    | Error  |  Rate  |                  |
+---+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 0 | 0     |  766.0 | 2718.0 | 0.7801 | (2718.0/3484.0)  |
| 1 | 1     |  351.0 | 6412.0 | 0.0519 | (351.0/6763.0)   |
| 2 | Total | 1117.0 | 9130.0 | 0.2995 | (3069.0/10247.0) |
+---+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

Actually, the only things that really interest me is the precision of the class `0` as `766/1117 = 0,685765443`. While `h2o` consider `precision` metrics for all the classes and it is done to the detriment of what I am looking for.

I tried to convert it in dataframe with:

```
model = grid_search.get_grid(sort_by='a_metrics', decreasing=True)[0]
model.confusion_matrix(valid=valid_set).as_data_frame()
```

Even if some topics on internet suggest it works, actually it does not (or doesn't anymore):

```
AttributeError: 'ConfusionMatrix' object has no attribute 'as_data_frame'
```

I search a way to return a list of attributes of the `confusion_matrix` without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to H2O documentation there is no `as_dataframe` method: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/_modules/h2o/model/confusion_matrix.html

I assume the easiest way is to call `to_list()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `.table` attribute gives the object with `as_data_frame` method.

```py
model.confusion_matrix(valid=valid_set).table.as_data_frame()
```

If you need to access the table header, you can do

```py
model.confusion_matrix(valid=valid_set).table._table_header
```

Hint: You can use `dir()` to check the valid attributes of a python object.